# How to prevent div from moving another div

Tags: html, css

I have two 2 divs. The first div has data been appended to it when a checkbox is checked . Now when i append data to the 1st div, it keeps pushing the 2nd div beneath it. I tried to set height and overflow for the 1st div so it does not push the div below it but it still does. How can i get this fixed, so that even when the 1st div is being populated, it does not push the div below.

```css
.panel-emp {
  height: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="panel-emp">
    <div style="overflow:scroll; height:70%;" class="panel_order">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" class="panel_2">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can we get a working example of this?

Comment: can you clarify which is the first DIV and which the second ?

Comment: panel-emp is the first div @samehanwar

Comment: and which div is moving lower ?

Comment: There is position fixed and absolute that break out of the document flow. Then there is also the float property.

Comment: @samehanwar, when i keep populating `panel-emp`, it keeps pushing `panel_2` downwards

Comment: @Daniel, property fixed and absolute don't help make my page responsive when i view on smaller screens. But on wider screens, it works well

Comment: Looks like you're using bootsrap.  .panel2 is a 'row' which would naturally put it below panel-emp.  Take the row class off... and also you have 2 class attributes on that div `<div class="row" class="panel">`

Comment: @RobertWade, i took row off and still the same

Comment: Change the height from % to fixed value. Solved.

Comment: see answer below

Comment: @Highdef, nice but when i increase the height, it still moves the panel_2 down

Comment: @XamarinDevil You need it to keep it at fixed value and then when you append data to it, it will scroll instead of moving the content below downwards.

Comment: @Highdef, yes i have given `panel-emp` a fixed height of 200px. The height is good but then it moves the div below

Comment: @Highdef, oh i get it. i think you are getting my question wrong. I am not talking about the the content moving downwards but instead it is pushing another div below

Comment: @XamarinDevil Cannot say much without seeing your actual html and CSS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few issues going on, but most of this boils down to improper use of bootstrap grids.

- You have two class attributes on one div.
- You're defining a bootstrap row on a div you want next to another one.
- You're bootstrap breakpoint class syntax is bad, you're mixing smalls and mediums.
- You're not nesting columns within rows properly.

This example puts your `panel_emp` and `panel_2` divs inside columns that are positioned next to each other using bootstrap classes.  On extra small screens they have equal width (6 columns). On small and up screens, they have 8 and 4 columns respectively.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="panel-emp">Panel Emp</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel_2">Panel 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Recommended Reading:**

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/